# FFmpeg/avconv not found

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, discord.js

when i try to run a discord bot in node.js, it comes up with this error

```
Error: FFmpeg/avconv not found!
    at Function.getInfo (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:130:11)
    at Function.create (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:143:38)
    at new FFmpeg (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\node_modules\prism-media\src\core\FFmpeg.js:44:27)
    at AudioPlayer.playUnknown (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\player\BasePlayer.js:47:20)
    at VoiceConnection.play (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\voice\util\PlayInterface.js:71:28)
    at play (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\index.js:259:14)
    at execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Frend Bot\index.js:239:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

i have installed both ffmpeg and avconv
i might be doing something really stupid and obvious, so please tell me if there is a simple solution

Comment: Is FFmpeg in your PATH?

Comment: Yes, it is in the folder.

Comment: Try to install ffmpeg-static. `npm i ffmpeg-static` It should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit on Pentium1080Ti's comment:

Assuming that you are using Windows, download ffmpeg binaries from the official source, extract to a folder, and then add the folder to your path environment variable.

To add to environment variables, hit Win+R and type in `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`. Open the Path user variable, and then hit create new, and paste the path in (make sure it's the /bin folder, the one with ffmpeg.exe inside). Save it, and it should be good to go.